# ConEmu switch between tabs with PuTTY tab open

Tags: putty, conemu

When I open new PuTTY tab inside ConEmu Ctrl+Tab / Ctrl+Shift+Tab keyboard shortcuts are unusable once that PuTTY tab gains focus.

Is there any way to fix this?

I might be missing something obvious as I have been only using ConEmu for two days and I'm still trying to understand all configuration options..

Comment: Do you mind coming and accepting the answer given by [Drew S](http://superuser.com/users/403911/drew-s/)? It is a straight solution without workarounds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you run or attach any GUI application in ConEmu tabs – all keyboard input (read focus) passed to this child GUI application.

That's why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work in your case – it is processed by PuTTY but not ConEmu.

But there is a way.

**Solution 1**

If you have enabled option "Install keyboard hooks" on "Controls" settings page, hotkeys with the <kbd>Win</kbd> modifier are still working!  Even the focus is inside child GUI application.  By default you may use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to switch tabs. These hotkeys are defined on the "Keys & Macro" Settings page.

**Solution 2**

Go to "Keys & Macro" page, find row with "Set focus to ConEmu" description and choose hotkey, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> for example. Please note that some key-combos may not work – Windows captures many combos.

So you can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> while keyboard focus is in PuTTY and after that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> must work. You can try this with Notepad – keyboard focus will be more obvious.

Comment: Thanks, Win+Backspace combination is a nice workaround. And btw I'm on Windows 8 which maps Win+Q to Search Apps action so I'm unable to use special keys..

Comment: You need to "Install keyboard hooks" on "Controls" page to make Win+Q working.

Comment: I have "Install keyboard hooks" enabled, but I've disabled Win+Tab and Win+Numbers, as I use them a lot.


I don't see Win+Q option though.. (I'm using 130220 x64 build).

Comment: Win+Q works for me on Windows 8

Comment: Yep, Win+Q was already described. But I rewrite answer to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 10):

I found a way for this to work with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Turns out I had `Settings > Integration > Children GUI > 'Focus on child windows'` checked. When I unchecked this option, I can now <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> insdie PuTTY

Answer (score 1):

For anyone thats using Cmder (heavily based on ConEmu) there is built in functionality for using win keys to tab switch:

`General > Support special hotkeys` + `Keyboard > Win+Tab - Switch consoles`

This automatically overides windows and app keybinds, but the above issues with putty based console will continue and will not switch console window just console tab. There is no "Controls" settings page in Cmder to try solution 1 of this answer, but the solution I found was to DISABLE this setting:

`Tab bar > Lazy tab switch`